# How to unlink/clone object from RealmDB in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm-database

RealmDB is magically linked with objects it adds, reads. But that overhead is not always needed.

I can manually read all fields and assign them to new object but what is canonical way to get data unbinded from RealmDB?